# Python script for Group Stats

Tags: qgis

I have a vector layer which is a grid. In the table attribute I calculated, using Zonal Statistics, the mean value of two raster layers, for each cell of the grid.

Now, I would like to use GroupStats to have some means value of a column compared to the second one.

For example :

```
R1   R2
10   15
10   25
11   14
```

I want to obtain :

```
R1    R2
10    20
11    14
```

So that is easy : [image: Group stats for mean value between two columns]

But as I have to do this a lot of time, I would like to write a Python script for this or to use Graphical Modeler.

But it seems that there is no module for Python, and no possible use in Graphical Modeler as it's a plugin.

Does someone would know how to manage with this ?

I use Qgis 2.18.9

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Calculating Statistics Based on Expression in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241083/calculating-statistics-based-on-expression-in-qgis)

Comment: It does what I want ! Thanks ! And I should succeed both with Graphical modeler and Python script so that's perfect.

Comment: Hi @J.Delannoy Can you share the python script regarding above ?